# React component delays the page load

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have 2 child components in my parent component, `CompA` and `CompB`. The second component does a lot of data processing (calls many other components as well for that), which delays the entire page load time. This causes my `Spinner` to get stuck after a while. Is there any other way to check if `CompB` is ready to be rendered and then render it, while the page already is loaded with `CompA`?

```
return(
    <div>
      <CompA
        info = {info}
        />
        <CompB
        data = {data}
        />
   </div>
```

Thanks for any help

Comment: Sounds like your component B is doing lot of some synchronous stuff? maybe show little bit more code..

Comment: True, it is passing data to multiple components , which renders SVG using D3. Also many calculations while drawing Axes is all slowing down. Specially when passing multiple arrays with more than 10000 items. Apologies for not being able to add extra code  cause have multiple components, but if any other idea to delay CompB loading at parent component would be very helpful.

Comment: Try wrapping the heavy part in `setTimeout`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will always experience some lack of responsiveness if you do heavy calculations on the main thread in JavaScript. This can result in the delayed rendering you are experiencing, or e.g. in less than optimal responsiveness of buttons and other user inputs.

The solution to this is to move the calculations out of your component and out of the main thread to free it up for rendering work.
You can initially render `CompB` in a blank/pending/loading state and update it later once the data you want to display is ready.

To move the calculations out of the main threads, you have multiple options, two of which are

- [using Web Workers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers) to perform the calculations in the background on client side, and
- performing the calculations asynchronously in the backend and passing the input and output via web services.